# Naive bayes classification for NO text-classification

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, feature-extraction, feature-selection, naivebayes

Modelling the feature space for a text document is quite easy.
For example, I can take every word from a text (training data) as a feature.
If a particular word (e.g. "dog") encounters multiple times in (classified) training examples (e.g. classified as spam), then I can take this word to classify new data.

How do I model my features, if they arent only words?
In my specific case, I have features like name, age and family size.
I don't think it is the right way to make an entry for every possible age in my feature vector.
If I assume that humans die by no later than 100, I would have 100 digits only for my age feature.
So I thought about data binning: Partitionate the feature "age" in maybe 1-20 yo, 21-40 yo, 41-60,...
To model a person with the age of 30 I would only need 5 digits now (01000).

Is there a better way to model features like these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that i found an [answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254203/mixing-categorial-and-continuous-data-in-naive-bayes-classifier-using-scikit-lea) [answer2](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-way-to-use-continuous-variables-for-a-naive-bayes-classifier-Do-we-need-to-cluster-them-or-leave-for-self-learning-Pls-help).
Hence one can model the feature with either data binning or by using a (normal) distribution that fits the continuous feature.